# Kit Carson & John Fremont expedition members

Tags: united-states, 19th-century, 1840s

I am trying to confirm that an ancestor traveled west with Kit Carson and John Fremont in 1842-1846, in one or several of their expeditions to map out western trails.  I am having trouble locating any sort of listing or schedule of the expedition members.  It appears that there were several expeditions to California and at least two appeared in published Congressional reports.

I have not yet located a source that lists the presence or enlistment of general members of these forays.  I don't have reason to know whether such exists, though I suppose as government expeditions there may have been some reporting or pay schedule.  It's also a subject of study as a historical event.

If it helps, my specific ancestor born 1809 would've been in his early to mid-30s for the expeditions, and the timing of his children did not seem to clearly preclude any of the missions.  His name was Harberd Rose, but with half a dozen different spellings and nicknames and misspellings: Harbird, Herberd, Harbert, Horbane, Harbans, Hary, etc.  I have him in North Carolina 1840 and Kentucky 1850, finally settling in Kansas.

**Post-Script (8/18/2014):**  After discussing this myth more with family, my partner did research on different people in the same line.  She started with ancestors of my grandfather, from whom the myth started.  She eventually determined that it was most likely a different line, one where my 4th-great-grandfather was probably merely in California at the right time and maybe knew Kit Carson and John Fremont.  My ancestor was there early on, but was probably not part of one of the expeditions and may not have had much if any interaction with that group.

I would still be interested if anybody knew of a source for information about these trips, or a source that covers a number of such historical expeditions.  It would confirm that my ancestor was not part of an official expedition there.

Comment: I have not been able to find an answer, but I have found  [a site](http://home.comcast.net/~jcfremont/jcfexpeditions.htm) with a list of voyageurs from his first expedition and a [book on his expeditions](http://home.comcast.net/~jcfremont/jcfexpeditions.htm).

Comment: I just wanted to confirm, is this your ancestor? http://www.findagrave.com/cgi-bin/fg.cgi?page=gr&GRid=25841840

Comment: Yes, that's him - though his wife's name was Grigory (sometimes Gregory) and Eliza Weech was his daughter in law, not his daughter. Though I will edit the question in light of new family rumors that changed the story

Comment: I am looking for descendants of John Fremont's expeditions to communicate with them about their ancestor's role in the journey. Thx!

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked into books written by any of the members of the party?  My ancestor was hired by a gold rush group as the hunter to feed them as they came from Wisconsin.  Upon his return, he hired a college educated woman to dictate his story about the animals of this newer part of the country.  Try out-of-print sites like AbeBooks.

Comment: Thanks, good suggestion.  Did they leave from Wisconsin?  My ancestor lived in Wisconsin for several years before going to California.

Answer (score 0):

There is the Fremont Memorial located alongside Oregon Highway 31, south of Silver Lake, that lists the members of the 2nd Expedition.

https://oregontic.com/oregon-historical-markers/fremont-memorial/